# No uninstall link against managed package

Tags: appexchange

I have a managed package on appexchange. Some of our clients have reported that they are unable to uninstall our package as they cant find the uninstall link beside our package.

I have checked it against dev orgs and i do see the unistall links. Has anyone faced this issue? What could be reason that we cant see the uninstall link.

Comment: This is obvious but, have you verified they have the required profile permissions to remove packages?

Comment: Can confirm that they had admin privleges.  Salesforce support had helped them remove the package.  Client has no clue as to what the support did